# Create PDF Form in objective c with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, pdf-form

i have to create PDF form which is content of Images and Text so , i am search on google i fine the way for text but no idea about image . some people says me user "PDF Form button" for display image but when my PDF open in Webview and click on button i need to see image library and choose the image which is set on PDF.
Anybody have idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello i'm using this `PDF` Library and i'm Satisfied using this Library,

Try This Library hope it's work that your way to like.

**https://github.com/derekblair/ILPDFKit**

Quick start:

```
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithResource:@"test.pdf"];
// Manually set a form value
[document.forms setValue:@"Derek" forFormWithName:@"Contacts.FirstName"];
// Save via a static PDF.
NSData* flatPDF = [document savedStaticPDFData]
```

Comment: Thanks @Super i see this link this is good but i have to put there image , and this working with text not with image.

Comment: @super  .. I want to use UIScrollview instead of UIWebview. I have array of images and wants to load images one by one with dropping my UIControls over it. Do you have any idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreGraphics to draw pdfs on iOS using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`, just like your can draw images using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.
While drawing on the pdf, you can add an `UIImage` to the pdf using `drawInRect`method :

```
 UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
 [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 200)];
```

You should check the guide [Generating PDF Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) from Apple.

Comment: Thanks @Michael i already used this but Do You Have any Idea About "PDF Form" which content Text Box and Button ? so i set image on Button and click on Button open image library and choose the image which is set on Button.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you for this, I've never used such an object, if ever it exists !

Comment: Thanks For Your help . @Michael